# Can I trigger a compiler warning when there is an implicitly captured "self" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

If I have some code that takes a closure, and `self` is implicitly captured, can I make it cause a compiler warning? Is there some flag I can add to the compiler command for this?

Comment: On my best knowladge you don't ...

Comment: Objective C compiler warns: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html
"The compiler will warn you for a simple example like this, but a more complex example might involve multiple strong references between objects to create the cycle, making it more difficult to diagnose."

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. But there is something that addresses what's presumably the reason you'd want this warning — to prevent situation where a closure capturing `self` can cause a retain cycle...

The potential retain cycle from capturing `self` in a closure comes up when the closure is passed as a parameter to a function but is used after the function returns — that is, the lifetime of the closure (and anything captured in it) "escapes" the context in which it's written. When the closure escapes, it has to be sure it still has access to the things it uses (like `self` and any properties or methods thereof), so we get into memory management and possible retain cycles, `[weak self]`/`strongSelf`, etc.

[image: no escape 1953]
[image: no escape 1994]

With `@noescape`, you can declare that closures passed as parameters to a function will not escape the calling context, and as such don't require the extra memory management overhead for closures that do. And the compiler can apply some other optimizations that make running your function and its closure faster.

```
func someFunctionWithNoescapeClosure(@noescape closure: () -> Void) {
    closure()
}
```

Within a `@noescape` closure, you can then access methods/properties on `self` without explicitly writing `self.`, because you're not capturing `self` anymore. And, once you label a parameter `@noescape`, if you try to do anything that would permit it to escape (say, take the closure from the parameter and assign it to a stored property), you'd get a compiler *error* (not just a warning).

For the full writeup from Apple, see [Nonescaping Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID546) in *The Swift Programming Language*. And [this post](https://medium.com/swift-programming/how-to-prevent-using-weak-self-inside-swift-closure-2c113b8b2651#.m4x0k6gqm) provides an alternate perspective that might explain things further.

Comment: Hi rickster, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, my case is that there are many people in my project who forget to make self weak, when calling framework APIs that take closures, specifically, RxSwift and RxCocoa. Your solution can work in some cases, but when we are calling framework code, how should this be handled?

Comment: If you're working with a framework that permits escaping closures but doesn't need to, you could write adapter APIs that redeclare/pass-through those parameters as `@noescape`, and require your team to use the adapters instead of the original APIs. (Something you could enforce easily in pre-commit hooks or whatever.) Otherwise...

Comment: ... you're beyond what the compiler can do and into the realm of static analysis (not least because whether any particular escaping closure *can* leak `self` doesn't guarantee whether it will). Xcode does have a static analyzer for catching problems *like* this, but I don't believe it currently catches this specific kind of issue. [That'd make a good feature request!](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Answer (score 1):

No, the only thing I can think of which can do anything similar is linting.

[SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) might be able to do something like that, and if not you can probably write your own rule for just such a thing.